# Memory Issue for Array Conversion

Tags: python, memory, numpy

If we convert a large array containing `0` and `1` as `boolean` to another array containing `0` and `1` as `float`, the size of array would be almost 10 times larger. What is the best way (if any) to handle this issue in python (Numpy) if we need this conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't have to do the conversion.  If you are performing some calculation with your bool array and another float array, the conversion will be handled during the operation:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype=bool)
x = np.array([2.5, 3.14, 2.7, 8.9], dtype=float)
z = x*y
print z
[ 0. 3.14 2.7 0. ]
```